# Changing theme in Xamarin.Android layout based on the logged in user

Tags: c#, android-layout, colors, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin android application which gets theme settings through a json file. The application font, colors etc, should be based on the values in the json file. I am not sure of the best way to handle this.

If I can add or update the colors to the resource file colors.xml at run time, those colors (and fonts) can be applied to all the controls in the view. But looks like its not possible to add/update colors at runtime.

Is it somehow possible to set the color settings to the root layout of the view, so that all the child controls can inherit the colors, font, etc.

Or is there a better way to do this? I am not using Xamarin.Forms and I have just one xml view (for now) with  as the base element.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to build or modify the theme programmatically during the app's runtime.

In very short words, you need to:

- Create an interface that allows applying custom colors, and fonts.
- Override every view class you use and make it implement this interface.
- in the `OnCreate` method of your activities, and the `onViewCreate` method of your fragments call this interface method on every view and its children.
- Finally, if you inflate new views somewhere else: recyclerView, bottom sheet dialog, other dialogs. Everywhere you need to do the same with these views.

I think with `Compose` you can apply custom theme settings while building the UI. But I didn't have enough experience with the Compose lib yet.

The task you are going to solve is not trivial, unfortunately.
And it is hard to make a library for this because in most cases you will need to customize your solution somehow.

Also, remember, that on the very first launch, you will still use the locally stored theme - the background of the splash screen, the icon tint colors, text views will have default (for the app) theme properties.

Usually, the cross-platform frameworks allow to customize the color themes locally, but it is impossible inside Android.

So, if you are looking for a solution provided by Xamarin, the UI should be built by its custom (if any exists) engine.

Comment: Do you have an example for this solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if my answer can help you - especially about using a JSON file as the control, but it is certainly possible to change themes dynamically in a Xamarin.Android or a .Net7 app.

If you check out my NavigationGraph tutorials at https://github.com/gmck for example either NavigationGraph7 or NavigationGraph7Net, you will see how themes (both light and dark) can be changed very easily. Android supplies attributes for this purpose. It can be done using either Material2 or Material3 themes as a base. Note none of these examples change fonts (but that could also be done).

Comment: I think I didn't make myself clear. I am receiving the font color, family, size, button background color, etcc from json. I am parsing it and store values in SharedPreferences. I am want to use those colors and fonts for all the controls in my view.

Comment: Forexample, I use this custom button. and I want to set the color of this button with the value I get from json.
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
  <layer-list>
   <item android:right="3dp" android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" android:left="3dp">
    <shape>
     <corners android:radius="12dp"></corners>
     <solid android:color="#3193e1"></solid>
     <padding android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp"    
        android:bottom="2dp"></padding>
    </shape>
   </item>
  </layer-list>
 </item>
</selector>

Comment: I understood what you were trying to do, I wasn't attempting to answer your question, I was just suggesting there is an alternative easier way to potentially do what you want.